# Performance issue with freemarker template

Tags: java, freemarker

I have migrated my code to generate a file using Xpand template to Freemarker template for performance improvements. But i still see some performance problems with freemarker. Below two methods are taking 40 sec together, see snapshot. Is there a way to improve the performance? 
Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Seems like template parsing dominates in your workload. While FreeMarker parsing is not particularly slow (for a relatively complex language parser), FreeMarker was designed with the assumption that you parse a template only once (which yields a `Template` object, that contains the template in an already parsed form), and then run ("process") it for many times. That is, that you will re-use the same `Template` object for several `Template.process` calls (that's what generates the actual output), each time with a potentially different data-model. Normally, if you get templates from `Configuration` (which should be a singleton, as opposed to being re-created again and again), those `Template` objects are cached. If you are creating `Template`-s with the `Template` constructor, then those are of course not cached, and re-using them is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

I used latest version of free-marker jar, the performance is 80% better than before.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).